# When do you use PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Every application I've made is on top of a database, web stack with Oracle as the repository.  Oracle PL/SQL has always been a mystery to me.  When do you use it?  Is it only in stored procedures (I don't do a lot of those either.)

When do you use Oracle PL/SQL?

Comment: Too broad, but [the documentation lists the advantages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#i9141).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle the language PL/SQL is used in packages, procedures, function and types. For further reading: [PLSQL Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm).

When using an Oracle database, PL/SQL is one of the most convenient way to access data directly.

PL/SQL code is very compact when interacting directly with data because there is no language barrier with SQL:

- Opening cursors, closing cursors can be done directly by the language when using implicit cursors.
- Binding is always done automatically for you when using static SQL.
- Static SQL queries are verified during compilation, which means no SQL synthax error at runtime.

Also by querying the data directly, you don't create an artificial cache. The benefit is that it is easier to implement safe multi-user lock mechanisms. Most web applications will pull data from the database, modify the data locally and upload it later. It is harder in such a case to protect the system from [lost updates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) for instance.

Since there can be many applications that interact with a single database, there is a further efficiency and consistency advantage in implementing business rules in a single central layer accessible to all applications: the PL/SQL layer.

Comment: So I'm guessing this is not for folks that need an ORM like Hibernate?

Comment: @johnny You still interface with a database. An ORM might simplify the interface somewhat but you're still dealing with queries, tables, indexes behind the scene. IMO for simple straightforward applications an ORM can hide the database just fine. But for many in-house applications where you need an extra edge in performance or scability, the ORM can get in the way to optimization. In that case you may find that PL/SQL is more appropriate and efficient. YMMV obviously =)

Answer (score 2):

It's used in stored procedures and packages, but also in triggers and database jobs (dbms_scheduler). Although for the latter 2 it's usually better to write a procedure and call that from the trigger or job.

When to use it depends on the overall architecture and where you want the business logic to be. Every Oracle system I worked on had all the application logic in pl/sql, which puts extra processing load on the database server but cuts down on the data transfer between the database and application layers. If you don't want to use the database other than as a repository there are cheaper options than Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

- PL/SQL is a Procedural Language
  extension of Structured Query
  Language (SQL).
- PL/SQL (Procedural
  Language/Structured Query Language)
  program executes on Oracle database.
  PL/SQL is specially designed for
  Database oriented activities.
- Oracle PL/SQL allows you to perform data
  manipulation operation those are safe
  and flexible. read more here [PL/SQL tutorial](https://way2tutorial.com/plsql/tutorial.php)

Here you can find [Advantages of PL/SQL](https://way2tutorial.com/plsql/plsql_advantages.php)

Here you can find official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm) list but it's too broad in my opinion.